# script provisioning olt huawei ssh2 with python

Tags: python-3.x, huawei-mobile-services, ssh2

I need to send commands to Huawei olt Software (MA5801). With ssh2 on my script python, I am connecting but the terminal says this:

```
Huawei Integrated Access Software (MA5801).Copyright(C) Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 2002-2019. All rights reserved.

MA5801-Lab-02-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx> Warning: Using the initial password is not recommended. Please change thenpassword.

MA5801-Lab-02-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx>Unknown command, the error locates at

MA5801-Lab-02-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx>Configuration console exit, please retry to log on
```

and this my code

```
import paramiko

transport = paramiko.Transport(('xx.xx.xxx.xxx', 22))

transport.connect(username='user', password='password')

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh._transport = transport

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('enable;config;interface gpon 0/1')

result = stdout.read(), stderr.read()

for line in result:
    print(line)

ssh.close()
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875)

Comment: I hereby contact you, please share the solution by posting an answer.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/manuel-cisneros-b932901b0/ This is my linkeding contact me here or +584143149027